# StackExchange Google Search

Tags: script, search

### Code

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        StackExchange Google Search
// @description Google questions if query begins with "gq:" and user profiles if query begins with "gu:".
// @version     1.1
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include     http://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include     http://serverfault.com/*
// @include     http://*.serverfault.com/*
// @include     http://superuser.com/*
// @include     http://*.superuser.com/*
// @include     http://stackexchange.com/*
// @include     http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include     http://stackapps.com/*
// @include     http://*.stackapps.com/*
// @include     http://askubuntu.com/*
// @include     http://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @include     http://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include     http://*.answers.onstartups.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    var query = document.getElementsByName("q")[0].value;
    if (!RegExp("^g[qu]:").test(query))
        return;
    event.preventDefault();
    document.location = "http://google.com/search?q=" +
        encodeURIComponent(query.substr(3)) +
        "+inurl:" +
        document.domain +
        ( (query.charAt(1) == "q") ? "/questions" : "/users" ) +
        "+site%3A" +
        document.domain +
        "+-site%3A*." +
        document.domain;
}, false);
```

### About

**With this User Script, you can override the built-in search with Google's.**

Just begin type in your query as usual in the search in the upper right corner, but prefix it with `gq:` to google all questions or `gu:` to google all user profiles.

Examples:

- `gq:unicorn` (finds a question with the word *unicorn*)
- `gq:"a unicorn"` (finds a question with the phrase *a unicorn*)
- `gu:unicorn` (finds all user profiles with the word *unicorn*)

#### License

I hereby release this script in the public domain.

#### Platform

This user script has been tested in Google Chrome 17.0.963.6 and Mozilla Firefox 8.0 with Greasemonkey 0.9.13.