# Search links (Stack, Google, Symbolhound) next to the search box, for tab opening

Tags: script, search

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

Adds three links next to the search box. Allows to open the regular Stackoverflow search in a new tab, or search using Google, or Symbolhound.
Proved useful to find duplicates.

#### License

Public Domain

#### Version

0.5

#### Download

[Install](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/161230.user.js) | [View](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/161230) (userscripts.org)

#### Source

```
// Add search links (SO, Google, Symbolhound), allowing to open them in a new tab
//
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Stackoverflow Search in Tab
// @version        0.5
// @description    Adds tab-openable links besides the search box
// @namespace      data:,000000000000000000000000000000003fbf49fdcc8f9ddb8de0d10f6a5c32ca
// @include        http*://*stackexchange.com/*
// @include        http*://*stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http*://*superuser.com/*
// @include        http*://*serverfault.com/*
// @include        http*://*doctype.com/*
// @include        http*://*askubuntu.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){

    // functionality
    var main = (function(){

        // append empty links next to search box
        $("#search").append(
            '<span style="position:absolute">'+
            '<a id="q_search1" href="/search?q=..." target=_blank title="Stacksearch, new tab">⬀</a>'+
            '&nbsp;'+
            '<a id="q_search2" href="//google.com/search?q=..." title=Google>G</a>' +
            '&nbsp;'+
            '<a id="q_search3" href="//symbolhound.com/?q=..." title=Symbolhound>$</a>'+
            '</span>'
        );

        // register update handler to populate ⬀ G $ links
        $("input[name=q]").bind("change input propertychange", function(){
            $("#q_search1").attr("href", "/search?q="+encodeURI(this.value));
            $("#q_search2").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/search?q=site:"+location.host+"+"+encodeURI(this.value));
            $("#q_search3").attr("href", "http://symbolhound.com/?q="+encodeURI(this.value)+"&l=&e=&n=&u="+location.host);
        });

        // temporary fix for missing space after [tag]
        var q = document.forms.search.q;
        if (q.value && q.value != "search") {
            q.value += " ";
        }


    });

    // inject function as last page script, so jQuery is available
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.textContent = '(' + main.toString() + ')();';
    document.body.appendChild(script);

})();
```

#### Platform

Works with Opera.
Tested in Chrome, but shows the links below the search box there.

#### Caveats

Runs as injected script, not in Greasemonkey context. But does not load external resources.
Does not update links with pre-existing search box content on page load.
Supposed to respond to key presses and pasted text, at least works in Opera.

#### Alternatives

Two similar scripts exist for Google or Symbolhound respectively. Alternative searches can be invoked with `sh:` or `gq:` prefixes there:

- [SymbolHound Search](https://stackapps.com/questions/3181/symbolhound-search)
- [StackExchange Google Search](https://stackapps.com/questions/3182/stackexchange-google-search)